# make fullScreenVideoView

Tags: android, android-video-player

I am creating my custom video player in android. I need requirement that when device is in portrait mode the height of `VideoView` is half of the screen and when i rotate device in landscape mode it should be fullScreen mode. But I cant not achieve this functionality

below is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="dp.com.player.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:id="@+id/video_frame">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CC000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layout_controller"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView android:id="@+id/time_current"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingTop="4dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="4dip"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/sick_bar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="32dip" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/total_duration"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingTop="4dip"
                    android:paddingRight="4dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/full_screenMode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_white_24dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dip"
                    android:paddingRight="4dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dip"/>
            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_frame"
        android:id="@+id/other_view">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and below is my activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private int brightnessValue;
    ContentResolver contentResolver;
    Window window;



    VideoView videoView;
    private String url = "http://aklearningsolutions.com/video/Nursery Rhymes.mp4";
    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView maxTime,currentTime;
    long totalDuration;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    LinearLayout mediaController;
    RelativeLayout frameLayout;
    ImageView pause,fullScreenImage;
    boolean isFullscreen;
    LinearLayout otherView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialisedObject();
        playVideo();




    private void playVideo() {

        Uri uri=Uri.parse(url.replace(" ","%20"));
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                updateControllerWidget(mp);
                videoView.start();


            }
        });
    }


    private void initialisedObject() {
        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sick_bar);
        maxTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_duration);
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        currentTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_current);
        mediaController = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_controller);
        frameLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_frame);
        pause = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        fullScreenImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.full_screenMode);
        otherView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.other_view);



    }

    public void fullScreenVideo(){
        otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit_white_24dp);
        isFullscreen = true;
        hideController(isFullscreen);

    }
    public void exitFullscreenVideo(){
        fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_white_24dp);
        isFullscreen = false;
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }



    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
             exitFullscreenVideo();
        }else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
             fullScreenVideo();

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: use setRetainInstance(true); in onCreate it will maintain your state when orientation changes

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want the layout to be full screen in landscape mode, if so

Create a new Layout for landscape mode in layout-land folder

Hide the `ActionBar` if you need to and then make the `VideoView` match_parent height and width wise in layout-land.

something like that

```
<VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

UPDATE:
This is not perfect, just a sample to show you how you can save the video position and then resume from there

```
private VideoView myVideoView;
private int position = 0;

//THEN OVERRIDE THESE TWO METHODS TO SAVE THE VIDEOVIEW Position BEFORE ACTIVITY GETS RECREATED

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //HERE WE ARE SAVING VideoView SATATE
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", myVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
    myVideoView.pause();
}


@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //HERE WE GETTING THE Position BEFORE VIDEOVIEW WAS DESTROYED
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
    myVideoView.seekTo(position);
}
```

Comment: I created layout-land but it is not working. For working it we removed android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection" from manifest file then result is that when we rotate screen video will be play from starting.

Comment: what happens actually is when you rotate the screen Activity gets recreated so you need to override `onSaveInstanceState` to save the video position, got me?

Comment: Can u explain more details how can we use onSaveInstanceState to save video position

Comment: always accept and upvote the answers that solves your problems so others could also take advantage of them as verified answer

Answer (score 1):

You should create one more layout in `layout-land directory` for landscape view
   [image]

Then in the new layout (landscape layout)

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"// change height to match_parent
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you don't want your layout recreate when rotate to landcapse, you should:
  + Detect orientation change by **onConfigurationChanged method**
+ Check if orientation is portrait-> change the height of `RelativeLayout` = 200 programmatically
+ orientation landscape -> change `RelativeLayout` = MATCH_PARENT

Comment: but we need requirement to fix the height of videoView 200 in portrait mode, for achieve this requirement I fix height of this layout 200. If we use match_parent that it display full screen VideoView in portrait mode

Comment: I created layout-land but it is not working. For working it we removed android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection" from manifest file then result is that when we rotate screen video will be play from starting.

Comment: @shaileshojha please see my update answer. hope it can give you an idea to solve your prolem

Comment: use `setRetainInstance(true);` in `onCreate` it will maintain your state when orientation changes

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh thanks for your suggestion but you can I in my activity code that I already set RelativeLayout = MATCH_PARENT programatically in fullscreenVideo method

Answer (score 0):

you mention         android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp" so obviously it does not come in full screen

Create `layout-land` folder and put below code with same file name and same id

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but we need requirement to fix the height of videoView 200 in portrait mode, for achieve this requirement I fix height of this layout 200

Answer (score 0):

May be becozz you have fixed your Relative Layout height

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 ==>    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"  <== here
        android:id="@+id/video_frame">
```

make it `match_parent` and in videoview `wrap_content`

and add this Flag in your Activity

```
                // full screen
               getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and if you want to hide the SystemUI bottom NavigationBar then use this.,

```
                  // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
            // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```